# TortoiseSVN not able to modify read-only path (on win10)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I faced with the problem and I googled it but can't find any solutions. So, sorry if I duplicated it.

When I am trying to commit changes using TortoiseSVN I got message

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: You (user) are not allowed to modify a read-only path. (you can find  
Error: the list of directories on the tool settings page)  
Error: Failed hook: pre-commit/00_pre-commit  
Error: If you want to break the lock, use the 'Check For Modifications' dialog or the repository browser.
```

The user on my computer has administrator access.

I noticed the following message:
*you can find the list of directories on the tool settings page*

but I don't know where I have to see it. 
I use https://www.assembla.com/

Added:
I tried to remove read-only mark in repository folder, but when I do SVN update, it returned.

Comment: Please read carefully: **blocked by pre-commit hook**. You have a custom script that's actively rejecting the commit. You also didn't seem to notice this: **If you want to break the lock, use the 'Check For Modifications' dialog or the repository browser.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is more simple. At https://www.assembla.com/ exists page where the administrator can config rules for directories for other users. Thank for help. All is working.

Answer (score 1):

The hook script configured on the repository forbids you from committing these changes. Check the hook script or ask your admin why you don't have permissions to make these changes.

If you are not an administrator, you can't solve the problem in any other way except by finding out why your commit is blocked and how you should adjust the changes you are going to commit making them complaint with the policy configured by the repository or project's admin.